# How can I set the width of form select boxes in Mobile Safari/iPad?

Tags: html, ipad, mobile-safari

I am developing a web-based menu application targeted solely for Mobile Safari on the iPad (in other words, I am not at all concerned about cross-browser compatability).  I have a form select box which contains a number of options the user can choose from to modify their order, which when clicked displays on the iPad as follows: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQrql.jpg)

The problem is that this box is not wide enough to show the user the price or even the full name for several options.  Smaller names is not a particularly attractive option in this case.  Is there any way in which I can either a.) set the width of this box (doesn't matter if it's a Mobile Safari-specific solution!) or b.) make it so that the box grows wider to accommodate the widest option?  I can find nothing on Google that deals with my question save for one forum thread with no useful answers.

Javascript is an option, if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: any code to see what you've tried so far?

Comment: Got nothing yet, since I have virtually nothing to go on.  Setting the size of the select box itself has no effect that I have seen so far.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem. I tried changing the "font-size" and "width" attributes on the select element and the options within it, to no avail.

Comment: Fortunately, since I posted this question, updates to iOS have improved the situation with these - the text wraps around and is made smaller to fit inside the box, keeping it from being hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge I believe UIKit entirely with the popup. The only advice I could suggest would be to implement it solely in JavaScript. I've had a quick Google and nothing is coming up that stands out as a existing one.

Comment: This is pretty much the only way to affect how these work, I think.  Apple seems to have this stuff pretty much on lockdown.